# Mocha Chai basic GET request not recording passes and fails correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, mocha.js, chai

I'm quite new to mocha.js so trying to get something fairly basic and reliable working with a minimal example.

I'm trying to do a GET request to an example JSON API and run 3 tests on it, all should have different results but all are getting different results than expected.

Additionally I'm trying to catch and count/report on the errors that occur through the tests to output details `after()` all tests are run in order not to clutter up the UI.

For the 3 tests I've got only 1 should be passing. The problem is that if I include a `.finally()` call then all of them pass, if I remove the `.finally()` call and have only the `.catch()` call then all of them fail. Not sure what I'm missing.

```
let errors = []

// After All output error details
after((done) => { 
  console.log("Total Errors: " + errors.length)
  // console.log(errors)
  done()
})


// Example Test Suite
describe("Example Test Suite", () => {

  it("#1 Should Pass on expect 200", (done) => {
    request("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/")
      .get("todos/1")
      .expect(200)
      .catch(function (err) {
        errors.push(err)
        done(err)
      })
      .finally(done())
  })

  it("#2 Should Fail on wrong content type", (done) => {
    request("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/")
      .get("todos/1")
      .expect("Content-Type", "FAIL")
      .catch(function (err) {
        errors.push(err)
        done(err)
      })
      .finally(done())
  })

  it("#3 Should Fail on contain.string()", (done) => {
    request("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/")
      .get("todos/1")
      .then(function (err, res) {
        if (err) {done(err)} else {
          try {
            expect(res.text).to.contain.string("ThisShouldFail");
          } catch(e) {
            errors.push({error: e, response: res})
            done(err)
          } 
          finally {
            done()
          }
        }
      }).catch(function (err) {
        errors.push(err)
        done(err)
      })
      .finally(done())
  })
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found two issues with the provided tests

1. `.finally(done())` finishes the test as successful immediately since `.finally` is expecting a callback and `done` is called in place instead, `.finally(done)` or `.finally(() => done())` might work as you intended them to.
2. intercepting the errors via try/catch is a really bad practice and your implementation will swallow potential errors while marking the test as passing, even though it failed, it is much better to use mocha`s test context for this is an afterEach hook, for example:

```
const errors = [];

afterEach(function () {
    if (this.currentTest.state === "failed") {
        errors.push(this.currentTest.title)
    }
});
```

It is also not required to call done when working with promises in mocha. A promise can be simply returned and mocha will pass the test if and when the promise resolves, fail it otherwise (if the error is uncaught).

```
it("...", () => {
  return request(...).get(...).then(...)
}
```

or using async/await, which returns a promise implicitly

```
it("...", async () => {
  const result = await request(...).get(...)

  // Do assertions on result
  ...

  // No need to return anything here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes good answer. What's the current suggested approach, to use explicitly acync/await, or implicitly use promises in Mocha?

Comment: I use async/await personally, it's more readable IMO